# Run GitlabCI during Merge Request and After Merge

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I make GitLab CI run on merge request and after merge?

Two branches, dev and master.
Two jobs, test and deploy.

On merge request from any branch to dev branch, CI will trigger. But I only want the test job to run for now. And when the merge request is merged it will then proceed to execute the deploy job. The reason being like this is, although all the tests will pass, we still can't proceed with the deployment because there might be some comments from validators in the Code Review that the dev will need to address. Only after addressing those comments and then if the unit tests are successful will then it be allowed to be merged. After the merge request have been merged, only then will it allow to deploy. The dev branch will be deployed to dev/test and master will be deployed to staging. Prod will be deployed manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `only` and `except` syntax to define the different jobs. If you are merging to your `master` branch, you could create a job called `before-merge` with the following syntax:

```
before-merge:
  except:
  - master
```

Then, your deploy job runs only for commits to the master branch:

```
deploy:
  only:
  - master
```

This way, the `before-merge` job should be executed for commits on all branches **except** master, and the `deploy` job will only be executed after the merge to the master branch occurred.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified

Comment: I get the idea and after reading the link i still couldn't implement what I wanted. The whole flow of the CI is on merge request, it will run the test job and after merging the merge request, it will then run the deploy job.

Comment: GitLab runs the pipeline automatically for every merge request and after a merge, since every commit triggers the pipeline - where does it fail for you?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig: How about if I want to run the deploy job only when the merge request is merged but not when the merge request created

Comment: @MinhNguyen It’s the same thing, just run your pipeline only for your main branch (e.g. `master`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the merge event.

The variables available after a merge are premium only says doc here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html

However,

- protecting main (or master branch) to MR only
- and
- triggering the after-merge pipeline on push to main (or master)

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of GitLab you want to use the following syntax as `only` and `except`, mentioned by *Philipp Ludwig* ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476203/3198469)), are deprecated.

before merge

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
```

after merge

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312893/18215208), because gitlab provided some predefined variables for this type of scenarios.